# cakephp3 and select2 how to reset the first value

Tags: cakephp, jquery-select2

I am using cakephp3 and select2 dropdown script.

My call to the data looks like this

```
$roles = $this->ParticipantsProjectsRoles->Roles->find('list', [
         'keyField' => 'id',
         'valueField' => 'description'
]);
```

within my view I call this

```
<?=$this->Form->input('role_id', ['options' => $roles, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control select2me']);?>
```

The output HTML will load always the first data entry into the select.
Is there a way to have the first value always empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `empty` key in the `options` array to `true` or another value, e.g. `Select Role`:

```
$this->Form->input(
    'role_id', [
        'options' => $roles,
        'label' => false,
        'class' => 'form-control select2me',
        'empty' => true
    ]
);
```

Comment: OMG! so simple! THANK you so much!! I was so blind!